# how to propagate error from convolutional layer to previous layer？

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, backpropagation

I've been trying to implement a simple convolutional neural network. But I've been stuck at this problem for over a week.

To be specific, assume there are 3 layers in a convolutional pass, marked as `l-1, l, l+1 -layer` respectively. And the `l-1` layer is the input layer with shape `(num_channels, img_height, img_width)`,the `l` layer is the convolutional layer with kernel shape `(num_kernels, num_channels, filter_height, filter_width)`, and the `l+1` layer is the pooling layer with pooling size `(pool_height, pool_width)`.  Note that in my simple implementation, the filters are 3-dimensional, and they have the same depth as with the input, i.e., they have the same number of channels as that of the input.

On this setting, I encountered a problem in the back-propagation phase.

I've studied many tutorials in neural networks, however, it seems that all of them stop with back-propagating the error to `l` layer with the formular:
\begin{align}
   \delta_k^{(l)} = \text{upsample}\left((W_k^{(l)})^T \delta_k^{(l+1)}\right) \bullet f'(z_k^{(l)})
   \end{align}
The question is, how should I back-propagate error from the `l` layer to `l-1` layer, that is, calculate $\delta_k^{(l-1)}$, in order to chain several conv-pooling pass together?

---

In my implementation, there is a class called `ConvPoolLayer` which has a `feedforward` method and a `backprop` method. The method `backprop` needs to propagate the error from output to input. When I chain instants of `class ConvPoolLayer` together, I just need train their `feedforward` methods and `backprop` methods together respectively.

Comment: You don't backpropagate to the *input* layer because that doesn't give you gradients that you can do anything with. So to clarify, you mean to use this in the case `l-1` layer is *not* the input layer?

Comment: I don't understand your notation, but essentially you backprop each set of feature map deltas (at each point) via the convolutional kernel exactly the same as a MLP layer, and accumulate them for each point in the input due to overlap.

Comment: @Neil Slater Yeah, I would like to use this in the case `l-1` layer is from another layer. In my implementation, objects (with different parameters) instantiated from the class `ConvPoolLayer` can be trained together. That is, the output of the previous layer might be used as the input of current layer. So I need to backprop the error to the input layer.